# localhost connects but local IP address not connect to server?

Tags: php, android, networking, wamp

I am using WAMP server. After starting server, when I type localhost in address bar in the browser, it connects and WAMP server page appears..But when i type local IP address, it says **Forbidden: You don't have permissions to access / on this server.**

```
I also try **127.0.0.1**,it connects well.
```

Please give me a reason and solution...

Comment: do you have a router between you and the Internet? When you say "I type my IP address" do you mean your Internet address of your router, or your **local** IP address?

Comment: which IP do you mean?

Comment: Perhaps this post should be moved to another forum.

Answer (score 0):

To access your wamp from your PC IP.

Go to apache > httpd.conf and search for

> Allow from 127.0.0.1

then add

> Allow from 'your ip'

then restart the apache service

WAMP denies from all as standard then lists exceptions